# Vmware Server2 Last known working kernel version

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-server

I hope there is some vmware expert here who can help me out.

I would like to know what is the lastest Linux Kernel version which known to work with Vmware Server 2.0.2.

What I using right now is 2.6.32 where the vmmon and other modules still need patching.

For higher versions like 3.x it wouldn't compile anymore for sure.

Comment: This product was discontinued nearly 5 years ago, serverfault is for professional sysadmins who would never consider using unsupported code.

Answer (score 1):

The last system I've been able to get VMware Server 2.0.2 working on was 2.6.18-128.4.1.el5 on a RHEL5 5.3 server.

If you have the luxury of something 2.6.32 or newer, you have KVM, LXC and many other options available to you. Don't look back. Move on from VMware Server.